# Concatenating multiple feedback messages

Tags: java, strings, formatting, optional

The goal is to build a `String` from a given set where `Feedback` is an interface and `DeliveryFeedback`, and `ProductFeedback`are its implementing classes.

```
private void formatOrderFeedbackZendeskBody(final ImmutableSet<Feedback> feedback) {
    StringBuilder feedbackMessage = new StringBuilder("The feedback: ");
    feedback.forEach(
                    f -> {
                        if (f instanceof DeliveryFeedback) {
                            feedbackMessage
                                    .append("\n\nType: ")
                                    .append(FeedbackType.DELIVERY)
                                    .append("\nReason(s):  ")
                                    .append(
                                            ((DeliveryFeedback) f)
                                                    .getReasons()
                                                    .stream()
                                                    .map(Reason::name)
                                                    .collect(joining("\n\t\t\t")));
                            if (((DeliveryFeedback) f).getComment().isPresent()) {
                                feedbackMessage
                                        .append("\nComment: ")
                                        .append(((DeliveryFeedback) f).getComment().get());
                            }
                        } else if (f instanceof ProductFeedback) {
                            feedbackMessage
                                    .append("\n\nType: ")
                                    .append(FeedbackType.PRODUCT)
                                    .append("\nReason(s):  ")
                                    .append(
                                            ((ProductFeedback) f)
                                                    .getReasons()
                                                    .stream()
                                                    .map(
                                                            ProductFeedbackInterface.Reason
                                                                    ::name)
                                                    .collect(joining("\n\t\t\t")))
                                    .append("\nArticle ID: ")
                                    .append(((ProductFeedback) f).getArticleId());
                            if (((ProductFeedback) f).getImageIds().isEmpty()) {
                                feedbackMessage.append(
                                        "\nNo images available.");
                            } else {
                                feedbackMessage
                                        .append("\nImage URLs: ")
                                        .append(
                                                ((ProductFeedback) f)
                                                        .getImageIds()
                                                        .stream()
                                                        .collect(joining(", ")));
                            }
                            if (((ProductFeedback) f).getComment().isPresent()) {
                                feedbackMessage
                                        .append("\nComment: ")
                                        .append(((ProductFeedback) f).getComment().get());
                            }
                        } 
                    });
}
```

I am getting the expected `String`:

```
Detailed feedback: 

Type: DELIVERY
Reason(s):  REASON1
            REASON2
Comment: another comment

Type: PRODUCT
Reason(s):  REASON3
            REASON4
Article ID: idsug
Image URLs: idsug, dfgh
Comment: comment

Type: PRODUCT
Reason(s):  REASON5
            REASON6
            REASON7
Article ID: dfddddddddgh
No images available
```

I just think this code is not very readable and maybe there is another better way to do this that I am missing :)

Edit 1:
Just to make clear, the usage of the `OrderFeedback` interface is only to give a type:

```
@JsonSubTypes({
    @Type(name = FeedbackType.PRODUCT, value = ProductFeedback.class),
    @Type(name = FeedbackType.DELIVERY, value = DeliveryFeedback.class),
})
@JsonTypeInfo(include = As.PROPERTY, property = "type", use = Id.NAME)
public interface OrderFeedback {}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I have (partially) rolled back the last edit. Please see [what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765).

Comment: @Pimgd, but it was a typo! :C 
I slightly changed just the names of some stuffs because code privacy stuffs, you know...

Comment: I'll rollback the rollback, but this is one of the issues as to why hypothetical ("my real code is something like this, but I'm not allowed to post it") is off-topic.

Comment: I replaced my comment about BadProductFeedback with an example of how to make use of a generic interface

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Polymorphism failure. Determine who is responsible for deciding what the output is supposed to look like and go from there. If the feedback is responsible, just implement and overload `toString()`. If the printer is responsible, find a way to get most of the detailed information into the interface.

```
if (f instanceof DeliveryFeedback) {
} else if (f instanceof ProductFeedback) {
```

This is just wrong.

Basically, what's the point of having the interface if you're just gonna side-step the interface and take a look at the implementing class?

For example...

```
if (((DeliveryFeedback) f).getComment().isPresent()) {
    feedbackMessage
            .append("\nComment: ")
            .append(((DeliveryFeedback) f).getComment().get());
}
if (((ProductFeedback) f).getComment().isPresent()) {
    feedbackMessage
            .append("\nComment: ")
            .append(((ProductFeedback) f).getComment().get());
}
```

Why does the `Feedback` interface not have a `getComment` method? Then you could just

```
feedbackMessage.append(f.getComment().map(c -> "\nComment: " + c).orElse(""));
```

Comment: Sorry about the `BadProductFeedback`, it was a typo while preparing the question. I have given more detail on the interface usage also.

Comment: Great idea! I added `getComment()` to the interface... For the code, actually I think this looks cleaner: 
`f.getComment().ifPresent(c -> feedbackMessage.append("\nComment: ").append(c));` WDYT?

Comment: @LorenaSalamanca ifPresent is better, I forgot it was available

Answer (score 2):

#### Interface over implementation

```
private void formatOrderFeedbackZendeskBody(ImmutableSet<Feedback> feedback) {
    // ...
}
```

It's strongly recommended to code against interfaces instead of implementations, so that you can easily switch the implementations when it is desirable, e.g. writing tests. This method should be accepting a `Set` instead:

```
private void formatOrderFeedbackZendeskBody(Set<Feedback> feedback) {
    // ...
}
```

#### Relying on `toString()`...

If you can modify the `toString()` implementation of your `Feedback` implementing classes, you should do that instead. The body of `formatOrderFeedbackZendeskBody(Set)` can be as simple as:

```
private String formatOrderFeedbackZendeskBody(final Set<Feedback> feedback) {
    return feedback.stream()
                    .map(Object::toString)
                    .collect(Collectors.joining("\n\n", "The feedback: ", ""));
}
```

#### ... or overloaded output building methods

Alternatively, you can use overloaded methods that take in a specific `Feedback` implementation (one of the rare cases where you'll actually want the method parameter to use the implementation), and a helper method to do the appropriate casting. It's all about managing the resolution outside of the stream-based processing. :)

```
private static String print(Feedback feedback) {
    if (feedback instanceof DeliveryFeedback) {
        return print((DeliveryFeedback) feedback);
    }
    if (feedback instanceof ProductFeedback) {
        return print((ProductFeedback) feedback);
    }
    return null; // or throw an Exception?
}

private static String print(DeliveryFeedback deliveryFeedback) {
    // ...
}

private static String print(ProductFeedback productFeedback) {
    // ...
}

private String formatOrderFeedbackZendeskBody(final Set<Feedback> feedback) {
    return feedback.stream()
                .map(ThisClass::print)
                .collect(Collectors.joining("\n\n", "The feedback: ", ""));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid the large indentation caused by the lambda. In this case, using a `for`loop results in much more readable code.